# How to deploy a specific images using skaffold buildpacks?

Tags: kubernetes, buildpack, skaffold

I would like to deploy a specific image in Kubernetes using skaffold buildpack. Everything is fine for doing the build but the deployment in Kubernetes failed because skaffold didn't use my dockerhub id as prefix, only skaffold-buidpacks is passed to silent kubectl command.

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta21
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: systemdevformations/skaffold-buildpacks
    buildpacks:
      builder: "gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1"
      trustBuilder: true
      env:
      - GOPROXY={{.GOPROXY}}
profiles:
- name: gcb
  build:
    googleCloudBuild: {}
```

Comment: We need some logs. Could you please run with `-vdebug` and include the output here?

Comment: I found it's my fault an other file should be changed, web.yaml

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBU[0027] Running command: [kubectl --context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes create --dry-run=client -oyaml -f /home/ubuntu/skaffold/examples/buildpacks/k8s/web.yaml]  subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
DEBU[0027] Command output: [apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
  selector:
    app: web
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: skaffold-buildpacks
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Kubernetes auto-generated script doesn't use docker hub image prefix

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I think you are saying that you used `skaffold init --generate-manifests`?  The  image names in the skaffold.yaml must match image names in the manifests, so if you rename the image in one file then you must rename it in the other to match.